# Solve for $x$ in $3\cdot 5^{x^2}+3^{x^2+1}-8\cdot 3^{x^2}=0$

Tags: calculus

$3\cdot 5^{x^2}+3^{x^2+1}-8\cdot 3^{x^2}=0$

Note that I didn't forget any parenthesis. I copied it as it is in my book.

I tried:
$$3\cdot 5^{x^2}+3^{x^2+1}-8\cdot 3^{x^2}=0 \Leftrightarrow 3\cdot 5^{x^2} - 5 \cdot 3^{2x} = 0 \Leftrightarrow 5 \cdot 3^{x^2} = 3 \cdot 5^{x^2} \Leftrightarrow ???$$

What do I do next?

Also, this $3^{x^2+1}$ confuses me. Does it expand to $3^{x^2}\cdot 3$ or $3^{x^2}\cdot 3^x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3^{x^2+1} = 3^{x^2} \cdot 3$ is correct.

Furthermore,$$ 5^{x^2} \cdot 3 = 3^{x^2} \cdot 5 \iff 5^{x^2-1} = 3^{x^2-1} \iff \Big(\frac{5}{3} \Big)^{x^2-1} = 1$$.

This happens exactly when $x^2-1=0$,or when $x = \pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$3^{x^2+1}$ indeed equals $3\cdot 3^{x^2}$. Proceeding from your last equality:
$$
5\cdot 3^{x^2}=3\cdot 5^{x^2}\iff 3^{x^2-1}=5^{x^2-1}\iff(x^2-1)\log(3/5)=0.
$$
The last $\iff$ above is obtained by taking $\log$ and simplifying. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$3\cdot 5^{ x^{ 2 } }+3^{ x^{ 2 }+1 }-8\cdot 3^{ x^{ 2 } }=0\\ 3\cdot { \left( \frac { 5 }{ 3 }  \right)  }^{ { x }^{ 2 } }=5\\ { \left( \frac { 5 }{ 3 }  \right)  }^{ { x }^{ 2 } }=\frac { 5 }{ 3 } \quad \Rightarrow { x }^{ 2 }=1\quad \Rightarrow \quad x=\pm 1$$